Error Running AdsPower Global on Linux After Installation
I recently installed Linux, and I am not a very experienced user. I tried to install the AdsPower antidetect browser. After completing the installation and attempting to run it using adspower_global, I encountered an error.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue?
AdsPower does support Linux, and they provide a file to download on their website, but I still couldn't get it to work.
Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.
Error:
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/opt/AdsPower
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Info:
My PC
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Download source:
https://www.adspower.com/download

Updated, thanks.

I downloaded and installed the software and got the same result as you. This happens due to changes in AppArmor which have been introduced in 24.04.
You can get it to work by creating an AppArmor profile.
Create the file /etc/apparmor.d/adspower with the following content:
# This profile allows everything and only exists to give the
# application a name instead of having the label "unconfined"

abi <abi/4.0>,
include <tunables/global>

profile adspower "/opt/AdsPower Global/adspower_global" flags=(default_allow) {
  userns,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  include if exists <local/adspower>
}

After creating the file run sudo systemctl reload apparmor.service to load the new profile or reboot the machine.
I tested this on my system (24.04.1) and it works.
